# Append messages to push notification - Firebase

Tags: firebase, web-applications, push-notification, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a WhatsApp like web app and want to notify the user for new messages. I am using push notifications by Firebase.

If a user receives a message1, a notification will be shown for "message1". 
When Message 2 comes, I want to appended it to the previous notification's body and not show a new notification.

Like "Message 1 \n Message 2" and so on.

Once the notification is read by clicking on it and when a new message comes in, say "Message3", it should be a new message in the body, without Message1 and Message2, which is already read.

My code for sending the notifications looks something like this.

```
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAlHKlaCE_______________________-NdJXkojLf9Ap9mu' );
    $data = array("to" => $key,
    "priority" => "normal",
    "collapseKey" => "demo",
    "notification" => array( 
    "title" => "New message",
    "body" => "message1 ",
    "icon" => "../profiles/p1.jpg",
    "tag" => "hello",
    "click_action" => "http://website.com"
    ));                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data); 
    echo "The Json Data : ".$data_string; 
    $headers = array
    (
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY, 
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    );                                                                                 
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );                                                                  
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );  
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Its just like whatsapp where a conversation's new message is added to the notification's body.
How can this be done using firebase?

Comment: why are there two negative votes on this post?

Comment: Question could've been little more formatted to make it easy to read and understand. But ya, its bad to get a down-vote without commenting what needs to be corrected. You got my vote and answer. hope it helps.

Comment: I've rephrased the question. See it both meets your need and correct if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tag and renotify" are the two things you have to use to achieve what you want. [Code example here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/notification-behaviour) under these two headings.

```
   const title = 'My Messenger';
    const options = {
      body: 'Message 1 \n Message 2',
      tag: 'MyMessengerGroup'
    };
    registration.showNotification(title, options);
```

Every time you get a new Message, use the same tag name as highlighted above. That will make sure it will overwrite the same notification, but with your appended message, like below.

```
   const title = 'My Messenger';
    const options = {
      body: 'Message 1 \n Message 2 \n Message3',
      tag: 'MyMessengerGroup'
    };
    registration.showNotification(title, options);
```

Use a messages array to store all the incoming messages. If the user have clicked on the notification, you can use "Notification Click Event" as explained in the code example link to flush out your "messages array" which you use to build the body of the notification.

Comment: The way in which u are addressing the problem is that i will have to keep a record of all the messages previous sent that have to be appended to the new message. Whereas, i dont want that. i wanted firebase to keep record of the old messages. But i found out that its not possible. Therefore, I am using a database for storing all previous messages in my database, and appending it to new message. Thanks for you help.